# Tortoise SVN delete a huge revision file without corruption of base

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I have a SVN pointing to Google Drive. A few days ago I committed a 6GB file. Due to connection problems, or some other incompatibility, this file gets stuck and the review is never updated with Drive.

Well, now I need to remove this revision (file), without the revision database being corrupted. It's possible?

```
Location: \db\revs\0
```

[image: File]

Comment: Storing a Subversion repository (and accessing it directly) on a cloud storage service like Google Drive, OneDrive, DropBox, etc. or even an on-site shared drive is a good way to get a broken repository.  That didn't happen here, but I urge you to reconsider where you're keeping your repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revisions in SVN repositories are immutable. Once data has been committed to Subversion repository, it will remain in the repository forever. Removing a revision or its content is technically possible, but is not a simple task. Read the FAQ entry [How do I completely remove a file from the repository's history?](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#removal).

Note that **you must never put live SVN repositories to Google Drive, DropBox and similar services**. Modern SVN repository is a flat-file database and those file sharing services will eventually break the repository and may cause data loss. If you need remote access to your repositories, deploy Subversion server to access it via HTTP(S) or svn://.